# Data Validation (Number greather than) in a Google Sheet is not working when changing the value in a script using setValue()

Tags: validation, google-sheets-api, criteria, worksheet

In a google web app I update data in a google sheet and I want the data entered to follow the data validation rules of the sheet.

I set the value in the google sheet cell using a google script.
A data validation (number > 10) is applicable to the cell of the sheet and in advanced options "reject input" is selected.
If I change the value in the sheet itself to 2 then the update will be rejected so the data validation (NUMBER_GREATER_THAN) is working!

If I do the same thing with a cell with a dropdown (Datavalidation VALUE_IN_LIST) then the update in the javascript is rejected and an exception will be thrown.

Strangely enough the exception is thrown in the getValue() and not in the setValue() but I can live with that. Apparently the datavalidation is asynchronous.
I think the data validation with NUMBER_GREATER_THAN was working a week ago but I cannot figure out what has changed or what I have changed.

My problem is I want the exception to be thrown for the setValue(2) since value 2 is not a valid number but it is no longer happening. While when I set an invalid string for a dropdown the exception does kick in.
Any ideas?

```
try {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    
   Logger.log("*** Number validation:");
   cellRange = ws.getRange(2, 7); 
   cellRange.setValue(12); // Valid number

   Logger.log('Cell-1 Before=[%s]);
   cellRange.setValue(2); // Invalid number
   Logger.log('Cell-1 updated!');
   Logger.log('Cell-1 After=[%s]', cellRange.getValue());  // No exception! 
    
   Logger.log("*** Dropdown validation:");
   cellRange = ws.getRange(2, 4);
   cellRange.setValue('Option-2'); // Valid string
   
   Logger.log('Cell-2 Before=[%s]);
   cellRange.setValue('Option-4)'); // Invalid string
   Logger.log('Cell-2 updated!'); // Not yet an exception 
   Logger.log('Cell-2 After=[%s]', cellRange.getValue()); // Exception for dropdown
  
} catch (err) {
   Logger.log('Set Value Failed: ' +err);
}
```

Output in the console:

```
*** Number validation:
Cell-1 Before=[12.0]
Cell-1 updated!
Cell-1 After=[2.0]

*** Dropdown validation:
Cell-2 Before=[Option-2]
Cell-2 updated!
Set Value Failed: Exception: The data you entered in cell D4 violates the data validation rules set on this cell.
Use one of the following values: Option-1, Option-2, Option-3.
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your expected result. Can I ask you about the details of them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I am sure it is not your English but my explanation. I tried to improve the explanation. It is a difficult subject to explain but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated question, about `My problem is I want the exception to be thrown for the setValue(2) since value 2 is not a valid number but it is no longer happening.`, I'm worried that in the current stage, there might be no method for directly retrieving the error message from this situation. So, as a workaround, if you already know the rule of the data validation, how about checking each value using the rule? I apologize that I cannot propose a clear solution. I would like to study more.

Comment: Sure that would be possible but I am developing a more generic solution that updates a row with fields in a spreadsheet and I just want to know if the validation is successful. Then the solution would work for any validation in the row in any cell of the row. In the meantime I found out that if I set a none numeric value then the exception does kick in. Beside that I think recently it did work correctly but I do not know what changed in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Thanks very much for digging into my problem and trying to find a solution. Hopefully someone else can help me.